# Is there any method to zero a matrix entry without changing eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The givens rotation can zero an entry of a matrix. But I would like to know is there any thing like givens rotation to zero an element without changing the eigenvalue of matrix?

Comment: Suppose that there were. Then applying it $n^2$ times, you'd get the zero matrix, which clearly has  different eigenvalues from a generic matrix $M$. So I think you need to be more specific in your goal.

Comment: @JohnHughes Actually I was looking for an orthogonal matrix $Q$ such that $eig(A) = eig(Q^T * A * Q)$ and an entry of $Q^T * A * Q$ be zero. you are right repeating this process get to zero matrix. Thanks

Comment: It still may be possible **if** you only allow **non-diagonal** elements to be zeroed. You would end up with a diagonal matrix and the eigenvalues are exactly the diagonal entries.

Comment: You might be interested in Jacobi transformation / Jacobi eigenvalue algorithm.

Comment: @Somos since the matrix is representing a graph, It doesn't matter what the diagonal elements are. just off-diagonal elements matters

Comment: @user251257 would you please provide some references?

Comment: @Drupalist it is "well-known". Just google it.

Comment: @user251257 I already tried google

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_eigenvalue_algorithm?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @user251257 Thanks. After setting to zero an entry, does this method zero other non-zero entries?